# Docusign DateSigned Tab Conditional value

Tags: docusignapi

From Docusign REST API, I'm trying to insert a DateSigned tab. It needs to be conditional. The value should appear only after when the recipient signs in the signature tab. I learnt that signature tab can't be made as Conditional parent tabs. I am using .Net web app. Any idea how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docusign restricts the usage of having Signature tabs as the Parent tabs and hence Signature tabs can't be used as Conditional tabs. [Closed]

Answer (score 1):

If you need the Date Signed tab to be conditional on a signature tab I would recommend having both signature and date signed a required radio button as the parent. This would at least meet the requirement of the date signed ONLY showing up with the Signature tab.

[image]

Once the radio button is selected (they cannot complete signing without it):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rickey. Well, the client wants the Date value to appear after recipient signing it.